# Почему в javascript шаблонных строках map цикл получается с запятыми?

Tags: javascript

Есть  javascript  код

```
 ` ${respons.some_array.map((item, index)=>`
    <div>${index}</div>
 `)}`;
```

это выражение возвращает код с запятыми

```
        <div>0</div>
     ,
        <div>1</div>
     ,
        <div>2</div>
     ,
        <div>3</div>
     ,
        <div>4</div>
     ,
        <div>5</div>
     ,
        <div>6</div>
     ,
        <div>7</div>
     "
```

После использования `join('')` запятые убираются

Почему получаются запятые и как на них действует `join`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Потому что `map` возвращает массив, который для перевода в строку пропускается через `toString`, который разделяет элементы массива запятыми.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/toString

`join` - метод массива, который возвращает строку, в которой строковые представления элементы массива разделены строкой, которая передана в `join` как параметр.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join